# FB friend-selector frame is in https and cannot interact with hosting page in http

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, coldfusion

I have implemented an invite your friends feature on a site.
Lately it stopped working (Due to the continues pleasure of the "stable" Facebook graph API...)
I'm trying to wrap my head around this one with no luck.
I get the following error whenever I interact with the friend selector frame:

> Blocked a frame with origin "https://www.facebook.com" from accessing
>   a frame with origin "http://myDomain.com".  The frame requesting
>   access has a protocol of "https", the frame being accessed has a
>   protocol of "http". Protocols must match.

my web-app is indeed on http rather then https, but this error is new as this feature worked in the past.

this is the code I use to open the friend selector frame:

```
  function sendRequestViaMultiFriendSelector() {
    window.fbAsyncInit();
    FB._inCanvas = true;

    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
        // the user is logged in and has authenticated your
        // app, and response.authResponse supplies
        // the user's ID, a valid access token, a signed
        // request, and the time the access token 
        // and signed request each expire

            FB.ui({method: 'apprequests',
                message: 'my message to my friends goes here'
            }, function(response) {
                console.log('requestCallback');
                console.log('request: '+response.request);
                console.log('to: '+response.to);
                //write response values to DB goes here... 
            });

            var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
            var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
        } else {
            console.log('sendRequestViaMultiFriendSelector, not connected');

            FB.login(function(response) {
                if (response.authResponse) {
                    console.log('starting again');
                    sendRequestViaMultiFriendSelector();
                } else {
                    console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
                    on_fb_fail();//...
                }
            }, {scope: "email,"+
                        "user_about_me,"+
                        "publish_stream"});

        }
    });
}
```

this is the code I use to init the FB api

```
 console.log('>> window.environment: '+window.environment);
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    console.log('window.fbAsyncInit, window.fb_inited: '+window.fb_inited);
    if(window.fb_inited === false){
    console.log('executing window.fbAsyncInit...');
    //if (navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft") != -1) {
    //if(/msie/gi.test(navigator.userAgent) ){
    if(navigator.appName === 'Microsoft Internet Explorer'){
        window.fb_inited = true;    
        FB.init({
            appId                : 'MY_APP_ID', // App ID
            status               : true, // check login status
            cookie               : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
            xfbml                : true,  // parse XFBML
            oauth                : true,
                    frictionlessRequests : true
        });
    } else {
        window.fb_inited = true;
        FB.init({
            appId                : 'MY_APP_ID', // App ID 
            channelUrl           : 'http://www.myDomain.com/channel.cfm', // Channel File
            status               : true, // check login status
            cookie               : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
            xfbml                : true,  // parse XFBML
            oauth                : true,
                    frictionlessRequests : true
        });
    }
    console.log('window.fb_inited: '+window.fb_inited);

    }
// Additional initialization code here
};

(function(d, s, id){
    window.fb_inited = false;
    console.log('Loading FB JS-SDK asynchronously...');
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

this is my channel.cfm

```
<cfsilent>
    <cfparam name="url.localeCode" default="en_US" />
    <cfset cacheExpire = 60 * 60 * 24 * 365 />
    <cfheader name="Pragma" value="public" />
    <cfheader name="Cache-Control" value="maxage=#cacheExpire#" />
    <cfheader name="Expires" value="#getHttpTimeString(dateAdd('d', now(), 365))#">
</cfsilent>
<cfoutput>
    <script src="//connect.facebook.net/#url.localeCode#/all.js"></script>
</cfoutput>
```

this is a quick cf port from a channel.php which I tried as well...

```
 <?php
 $cache_expire = 60*60*24*365;
 header("Pragma: public");
 header("Cache-Control: max-age=".$cache_expire);
 header('Expires: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', time()+$cache_expire) . ' GMT');
 ?>
 <script src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
```

would REALLY appreciate any ideas
I heared Facebook is not updating their reference in sync with their changes, hence the 'pleasure' in working with their API... 
I based my scripts on these links:
FB.init -  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/
FB friends requests - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/

Answer (score 0):

I added these two lines of code to break the iFrame and it solved the exception

```
if (top.location!= self.location){
  top.location = self.location
}
```

this solves the different protocols issue...
on with the other bugs...

Comment: Does anyone know if app invitations moved from appearing as regular notifications to appear only in the app center? <br> I know for a fact that last time I tested this invite your friends feature on my site, it sent invitations that got through and were displayed in the notifications at the top bar of the user, now I can only found them in the app-center. <br>I am not sure about this since I have sent quite a few invitation to the same test user so facebook might label them differently...